# Implementing Circular Linked List in java

Tags: java, circular-list

I'm having a bit of an issue with implementing my circularly linked list. I'm working on a problem that requires you to implement any ADT yourself. I seem to be okay with adding nodes to the list, however I'm in unfamiliar territory when it comes to removing. I included the first two remove methods to give you an idea of where my head is at, how would I go about removing the last node in the list?

```
public class LinkedList {
    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private int size = 0;
    LinkedList() {
        head = null;
        current = null;
        previous = null;
        tail = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    //checks if list is empty
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return head == null;
    }
    //add new node to front of circularly linked list
    public void addToFront(E x) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(x);
        } else {
            Node n = new Node(x);
            x.next() = head;
            head = x;
        }
    }

    public void addtoMiddle(E x) {
        x.next = current.next();
        current.next = x;
        size = size + 1;
    }

    public void addToEnd(E x) {
        x.next = null;
        tail.next() = x;
        tail = x;
        size = size + 1;
    }

    public void removeFirst(E x) {
        if (head = null) {
            System.out.println("Error! List is empty!");
        } else {
            head = current.next();
            size = size + 1;
        }
    }

    public void removeMiddle(E x) {
        previous.next() = current.next();
        current.next() = null;
        size = size + 1;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the `Node` class as well? Assuming you have links in both directions removing the last node would just require you to go backwards from the head. Shouldn't be too big of a headache. - If you have only links in one direction then loop until you hit a node whose `next` points to the head. That's your last node then.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'circularly linked list"?

Comment: This isn't a *circular* linked list, just a doubly linked list - which could be made into a circular linked list. A circular linked list never has null in any of the nodes' next and previous fields.

Comment: @Thomas -- I am a beginner & trying to absorb like a sponge. I know there are mistakes/missing statements & am just looking a push in the right direction. Thank you. What "node class" are you referring to?

Comment: @pablokunta128 I'll add an answer for formatting reasons.

Comment: The constructor LinkedList refers to current and previous - where are their declarations?

Comment: @laune How would you go about making a doubly linked list into a circular one? Thank you

Comment: @laune where should the declarations be? Oh i see, I declared them in the LinkedList method, and not the class. Is that it?

Comment: You didn't declare them anywhere in this class, but I think they are redundant anyway.

Comment: @laune How would one go about adding/removing from the middle without a current then?

Comment: addToFront doesn't increment size. Both remove methods increment size.

Comment: You still haven't added the code for Node, so I don't know what to make of previous and current in method removeMiddle. Also, I wonder about the purpose of `E x` in the remove methods.

Comment: Stop editing the question - this discussion won't make any sense if you remove the reasons for comments.

Comment: With all due respect, "x.next() = head;" is not even legal Java code, and it will not compile. Perhaps you should learn the basic rules of Java first. (I assume this is a homework assignment, but having people on this site write your homework for you is not going to help you in the long run.)

Comment: @cpurdy you're correct. I'm a beginner and I have been struggling with the coding aspect. I posted in order to get some advice on implementation, not to have someone write my work. I do plan on having a CS career, so I'm aware it would counterproductive to have others do it for me. Thank you for the advice

Comment: In that case, start with a CircularLinkedList<T> implementation that has only one field: Node head; .. and a Node that has only two fields: T value; and Node next; .. that should be enough constraint on design to force you to implement a proper circular linked list. And best wishes!

Answer (score 3):

In a circular linked list the last node's `next` points to the head, so you loop through your nodes until `node.next.equals( head )`. Note that `next` must never be null and if you have only one node then you have `head.next = head`.

In a circular doubly linked list you also have a `previous` node, i.e. you can iterate backwards. In that case your last node is just `head.previous`.

A small ascii picture:

```
head -next---> node -next---> node -next---> last
 | ^  <---prev-      <---prev-      <---prev- | ^
 | |                                          | |
 | |_____________________________________next_| |
 |_prev_________________________________________|
```

Comment: So in theory all I would need is a "head", "tail", and i'll be able to ascertain the methods for removing/adding the middle/end while using .next & .previous?

Comment: A very good way of implementing a circular doubly linked list is to make `List extends Node` so that the list object has the same pointers as a node. This way, there's no need to distinguish the empty list from a list with nodes.

Comment: @laune is there a way we can continue this into chat? I don't have enough reputation yet to initialize the convo however. I'm curious to pick your brain & learn a little more. Thank you

Comment: @pablokunta128 you'd probably just need the head but keeping track of the tail would come in handy in certain situations. Just as a side note: `addtoMiddle` etc. seems a bit odd because you'd basically just add at any location (adding to front and back are just special cases for that) so the term "middle" might be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not directly an answer to your question but I feel like [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637853/thomas) has given the needed explanation here.

Since you have a lot of syntax or incompleteness errors in the example
I would recommend to comment out all functions so it has no more errors. Then comment them in again one by one correcting every error.

Some advices:

You use class members which are not defined e.g. `current`, `previous`.

Decide if `next` should be a member or function.

You need to define a class for `Node` (containing its members and functions), like you did for `LinkedList`.